# Simplest voltage-controlled constant current source outputting 500 mA

Tags: circuit-design, current-source, constant-current

I'm trying to design a very simple, beginner-friendly voltage controlled current source that will output 0.5 A through a load resistor. The load (some current-activated nitinol wire) will be about 10 Ohms in impedance (edited). I'm thinking a simple design consisting of an operational amplifier, and a MOSFET. My source voltage to power the circuit will be 9V (from a battery). Can someone please help me?

Picture of the current circuit design I have in mind, which is not behaving as expected (not reaching .5 V drop across R2):

[image]

Comment: Let's see the schematic you have so far.

Comment: 9 V is not enough to put 0.5 A through 100s ohms.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the details about the mapping between control voltage and current Also 9V through a 100 ohms is a wee bit less than 0.5A, (but rather 0.09A) so 9V is not sufficient.

Comment: Also there’s a question of whether you want to use an op-amp or would be fine with a couple transistors. What accuracy does the voltage to current mapping need? A looser spec is better to implement. But spec it out. Edit the question to add the details we ask for, and flag the comments as “no longer needed”.

Comment: And what is the load exactly? Is it a resistor/heater or something else?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  V=I*R, so if R=100 Ohms and I=0.5A, you'd need at least 50 volts to force that current through the resistor.  Beyond that, it's not a hard problem.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. Just updated my question with the proposed circuit.

Comment: @Bee yeah, so everyone is right about 9V / 100 Ω << 0.5 A. So, obviously, your circuit can't work.

Comment: Simplest within what range of operating parameters: accuracy, stability, compliance (output voltage) range, efficiency, etc.? A single transistor is a trivial solution, but has many downsides; constraints are required to refine it to a "simplest" and, presumably, "practical" realization.

Answer (score 4):

The error in your simulation is that R2 is 0.5 ohms and V2 is 1 volt. 1/0.5 = 2A, not 0.5. Change V2 to be 0.5V and R2 to be 1 ohm.

The reason that the circuit isn't reaching 2As is that 9V/(0.5+10+0.5) is around 812mA (V1/Rser+Load+R2) which is what you're seeing in the simulation.